# Is it possible to create a glow effect in SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm learning SVG and I would like to know if it is possible to create this kind of glow effect with SVG, interactively as in the following example -hovering trigger the effect - https://codepen.io/FelixRilling/pen/qzfoc

The fact is that I'm wondering how make the light come and go, the advantage of SVG would be a more accurate effect with better shape following, this kind of advantage. Is it possible to do that with SVG?

```css
body {
  background-color: #222222;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #2b2b2b 0%, #2b2b2b 10%, #222222 0%, #222222 50%) 0 / 15px 15px;
}

#container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}


/*Neon*/

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 7em;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

p:nth-child(1) a {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Monoton;
  -webkit-animation: neon1 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: neon1 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: neon1 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

p:nth-child(1) a:hover {
  color: #FF1177;
  -webkit-animation: none;
  -moz-animation: none;
  animation: none;
}

p:nth-child(2) a {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #228DFF;
  font-family: Iceland;
}

p:nth-child(2) a:hover {
  -webkit-animation: neon2 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: neon2 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: neon2 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

p:nth-child(3) a {
  color: #FFDD1B;
  font-family: Pacifico;
}

p:nth-child(3) a:hover {
  -webkit-animation: neon3 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: neon3 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: neon3 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

p:nth-child(4) a {
  color: #B6FF00;
  font-family: "Press Start 2P";
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

p:nth-child(4) a:hover {
  -webkit-animation: neon4 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: neon4 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: neon4 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

p:nth-child(5) a {
  color: #FF9900;
  font-family: Audiowide;
}

p:nth-child(5) a:hover {
  -webkit-animation: neon5 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: neon5 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: neon5 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

p:nth-child(6) a {
  color: #BA01FF;
  font-family: Vampiro One;
}

p:nth-child(6) a:hover {
  -webkit-animation: neon6 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: neon6 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: neon6 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

p a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}


/*glow for webkit*/

@-webkit-keyframes neon1 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #FF1177, 0 0 70px #FF1177, 0 0 80px #FF1177, 0 0 100px #FF1177, 0 0 150px #FF1177;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #FF1177, 0 0 35px #FF1177, 0 0 40px #FF1177, 0 0 50px #FF1177, 0 0 75px #FF1177;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes neon2 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #228DFF, 0 0 70px #228DFF, 0 0 80px #228DFF, 0 0 100px #228DFF, 0 0 150px #228DFF;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #228DFF, 0 0 35px #228DFF, 0 0 40px #228DFF, 0 0 50px #228DFF, 0 0 75px #228DFF;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes neon3 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #FFDD1B, 0 0 70px #FFDD1B, 0 0 80px #FFDD1B, 0 0 100px #FFDD1B, 0 0 150px #FFDD1B;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #FFDD1B, 0 0 35px #FFDD1B, 0 0 40px #FFDD1B, 0 0 50px #FFDD1B, 0 0 75px #FFDD1B;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes neon4 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #B6FF00, 0 0 70px #B6FF00, 0 0 80px #B6FF00, 0 0 100px #B6FF00, 0 0 150px #B6FF00;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #B6FF00, 0 0 35px #B6FF00, 0 0 40px #B6FF00, 0 0 50px #B6FF00, 0 0 75px #B6FF00;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes neon5 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #FF9900, 0 0 70px #FF9900, 0 0 80px #FF9900, 0 0 100px #FF9900, 0 0 150px #FF9900;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #FF9900, 0 0 35px #FF9900, 0 0 40px #FF9900, 0 0 50px #FF9900, 0 0 75px #FF9900;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes neon6 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #ff00de, 0 0 70px #ff00de, 0 0 80px #ff00de, 0 0 100px #ff00de, 0 0 150px #ff00de;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #ff00de, 0 0 35px #ff00de, 0 0 40px #ff00de, 0 0 50px #ff00de, 0 0 75px #ff00de;
  }
}


/*glow for mozilla*/

@-moz-keyframes neon1 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #FF1177, 0 0 70px #FF1177, 0 0 80px #FF1177, 0 0 100px #FF1177, 0 0 150px #FF1177;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #FF1177, 0 0 35px #FF1177, 0 0 40px #FF1177, 0 0 50px #FF1177, 0 0 75px #FF1177;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes neon2 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #228DFF, 0 0 70px #228DFF, 0 0 80px #228DFF, 0 0 100px #228DFF, 0 0 150px #228DFF;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #228DFF, 0 0 35px #228DFF, 0 0 40px #228DFF, 0 0 50px #228DFF, 0 0 75px #228DFF;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes neon3 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #FFDD1B, 0 0 70px #FFDD1B, 0 0 80px #FFDD1B, 0 0 100px #FFDD1B, 0 0 150px #FFDD1B;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #FFDD1B, 0 0 35px #FFDD1B, 0 0 40px #FFDD1B, 0 0 50px #FFDD1B, 0 0 75px #FFDD1B;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes neon4 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #B6FF00, 0 0 70px #B6FF00, 0 0 80px #B6FF00, 0 0 100px #B6FF00, 0 0 150px #B6FF00;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #B6FF00, 0 0 35px #B6FF00, 0 0 40px #B6FF00, 0 0 50px #B6FF00, 0 0 75px #B6FF00;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes neon5 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #FF9900, 0 0 70px #FF9900, 0 0 80px #FF9900, 0 0 100px #FF9900, 0 0 150px #FF9900;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #FF9900, 0 0 35px #FF9900, 0 0 40px #FF9900, 0 0 50px #FF9900, 0 0 75px #FF9900;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes neon6 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #ff00de, 0 0 70px #ff00de, 0 0 80px #ff00de, 0 0 100px #ff00de, 0 0 150px #ff00de;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #ff00de, 0 0 35px #ff00de, 0 0 40px #ff00de, 0 0 50px #ff00de, 0 0 75px #ff00de;
  }
}


/*glow*/

@keyframes neon1 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #FF1177, 0 0 70px #FF1177, 0 0 80px #FF1177, 0 0 100px #FF1177, 0 0 150px #FF1177;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #FF1177, 0 0 35px #FF1177, 0 0 40px #FF1177, 0 0 50px #FF1177, 0 0 75px #FF1177;
  }
}

@keyframes neon2 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #228DFF, 0 0 70px #228DFF, 0 0 80px #228DFF, 0 0 100px #228DFF, 0 0 150px #228DFF;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #228DFF, 0 0 35px #228DFF, 0 0 40px #228DFF, 0 0 50px #228DFF, 0 0 75px #228DFF;
  }
}

@keyframes neon3 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #FFDD1B, 0 0 70px #FFDD1B, 0 0 80px #FFDD1B, 0 0 100px #FFDD1B, 0 0 150px #FFDD1B;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #FFDD1B, 0 0 35px #FFDD1B, 0 0 40px #FFDD1B, 0 0 50px #FFDD1B, 0 0 75px #FFDD1B;
  }
}

@keyframes neon4 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #B6FF00, 0 0 70px #B6FF00, 0 0 80px #B6FF00, 0 0 100px #B6FF00, 0 0 150px #B6FF00;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #B6FF00, 0 0 35px #B6FF00, 0 0 40px #B6FF00, 0 0 50px #B6FF00, 0 0 75px #B6FF00;
  }
}

@keyframes neon5 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #FF9900, 0 0 70px #FF9900, 0 0 80px #FF9900, 0 0 100px #FF9900, 0 0 150px #FF9900;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #FF9900, 0 0 35px #FF9900, 0 0 40px #FF9900, 0 0 50px #FF9900, 0 0 75px #FF9900;
  }
}

@keyframes neon6 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #ff00de, 0 0 70px #ff00de, 0 0 80px #ff00de, 0 0 100px #ff00de, 0 0 150px #ff00de;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #ff00de, 0 0 35px #ff00de, 0 0 40px #ff00de, 0 0 50px #ff00de, 0 0 75px #ff00de;
  }
}


/*REEEEEEEEEEESPONSIVE*/

@media (max-width: 650px) {
  #container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 3.5em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <p><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red">
            RED
        </a></p>

  <p><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue">
            BLUE
        </a></p>

  <p><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow">
            Yellow
        </a></p>

  <p><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green">
            GREEN
        </a></p>

  <p><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_(colour)">
            ORANGE
        </a></p>

  <p><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violet_(color)">
            VIOLET
        </a></p>

</div>

<div id="linkBack" style="position:absolute;right:0px;top:0px;background-color:#333;margin:0;width:60px;padding:5px"><a href="http://www.f-rilling.com/projects/" target="_blank" style="font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;color:#fff;padding:0 0 0 5px;font-family:sans-serif">My Site</a></div>
```

Comment: Did you try this, replacing the fonts with an SVG image?

Comment: I'm very new to svg and I'm very wondering if it is just possible to do that, I have make some searches on the web but didn't found any example of this effect in SVG. So I'm wondering if SVG has the capacity to do that easily or comfortably at minimum, that y very question indeed

Comment: But did you try this, replacing the fonts with an SVG image? :) See what it does

Comment: No I don't my honor ^^, because the effect here use CSS to make the glow, and I'm wondering if we can obtain the same effect, confortably in SVG

Comment: Yes, hence my question. The code you provided takes a text and applies a glow effect to it. Now try to take the same code, replace the text with a SVG image, and see what it does.

Comment: Okay I will try it, meanwhile I think it would result the same

Comment: ...well if the result is the same, it means you can. Problem solved.

Comment: Yes I understand you and thanks for your assist, in fact I would make this effect in pure SVG, not with CSS, that was my question more precisely^^

Comment: Aaaaaaah, I get it now >_< Well the answer is clearly yes, because Illustrator has a "[glow](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/drop-shadows-glows-feathering.html)" filter, so yes, your SVG can glow. But this question doesn't belong to Stackoverflow, it's about vector design, that's why I was so confused

Comment: You could try with svg filters, but svg shadow filters have no concept of spread (in css shadow terms), so it may not be as easy to get as strong a glow effect.

Answer (score 22):

Yes it's possible.

The basic idea is to use a filter to blur the shape, colour the blurred shape to your neon colour, then put it behind the original text.

However to achieve the best neon glow, you need to tinker with the colours and the intensity of the glow.  In the following example, I have used a series of blurs of different amounts stacked together to achieve a better effect.  This is a similar approach to the codepen you have linked to.  But there will be other ways to do it also.

Note that, for simplicity, the particular filter definition used here expects the original shape (the text) to be white.  It may not work well with other colours.  But the filter can be tweaked to get around that issue.

```css
svg {
  background-color: black;
  width: 400px;
}

text {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sansserif;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 900;
  fill: white;
  filter: url(#red-glow);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400">
  <defs>
    <filter id="red-glow" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
       <!-- blur the text at different levels-->
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5" result="blur5"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur10"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="20" result="blur20"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="30" result="blur30"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="50" result="blur50"/>
      <!-- merge all the blurs except for the first one -->
      <feMerge result="blur-merged">
        <feMergeNode in="blur10"/>
        <feMergeNode in="blur20"/>
        <feMergeNode in="blur30"/>
        <feMergeNode in="blur50"/>
      </feMerge>
      <!-- recolour the merged blurs red-->
      <feColorMatrix result="red-blur" in="blur-merged" type="matrix"
                     values="1 0 0 0 0
                             0 0.06 0 0 0
                             0 0 0.44 0 0
                             0 0 0 1 0" />
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="red-blur"/>       <!-- largest blurs coloured red -->
        <feMergeNode in="blur5"/>          <!-- smallest blur left white -->
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>  <!-- original white text -->
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <text x="200" y="200" text-anchor="middle">RED</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: It might be usefull to know that the second-last number of the feColorMatrix has the same effect as the feComponentTransfer in my solution and intensifies the glow if raised.

Answer (score 16):

Here's a basic setup:

```html
<svg width="100%" height="300">
  <filter id="neon">
    <feFlood flood-color="rgb(255,255,128)" flood-opacity="0.5" in="SourceGraphic" />
    <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10" />
    <feComponentTransfer result="glow1">
      <feFuncA type="linear" slope="4" intercept="0" />
    </feComponentTransfer>
    <feMerge>
       <feMergeNode in="glow1" />
       <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
    </feMerge>
  </filter>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
  <text text-anchor="middle" font-size="100" font-family="sans-serif" x="50%" y="200" fill="yellow" filter="url(#neon)">NEON</text>
</svg>
```

- `flood-color` is the glow color
- `stdDeviation` is the approx size, with higher values meaning less intensity
- `slope` intensifies the glow and counteracts dilution of the Gaussian Blur. `flood-opacity` does the same, but has an upper limit of 1
- if you want to get the glow in front of the letters, change the order of the `<feMergeNode>`s
- if you want to overlay multiple glow layers like in the pen, repeat the filter primitives except the final `<feMerge>` and add their result in the order you want them to `<feMerge>`

Comment: That's not basic, it's great! Good explanation too, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's late, but here's some code I wrote ages ago:

```css
.image{
filter: url(#glow);
width:200px;
height:auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_girl.jpg" class="image" width="500" height="600">
<svg width="0" height="0" id="glow__svg_">
  <filter
    id="glow"
  >
  >
    <feGaussianBlur
      in="SourceGraphic"
      stdDeviation="10"
      result="glow__svg__blur"
      id="glow__svg__res"
    />
    <feBlend
      mode="lighten"
      in="SourceGraphic"
      in2="glow__svg__blur"
    />
  </filter>
</svg>
```

Just play with the `stdDeviation` in `feGaussianBlur` and the `mode` in `feBlend`. 
 
I usually do something like this:

```html
    <style>
        
        body {
            background: #000;
        }
        .image {
            filter: url(#glow);
            width: 200px;
            height: auto;
            margin:50px; 
            padding:50px;
        }
    </style>
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_girl.jpg" class="image" width="500" height="600">
       <svg width="0" height="0" id="glow__svg_">
<filter
    id="glow"
>
    <feGaussianBlur
        in="SourceGraphic"
        stdDeviation="20"
        result="glow__svg__blur"
        id="glow__svg__res"
    />
    <feColorMatrix
        type="saturate"
        in="glow__svg__blur"
        values="2"
        result="glow__svg__sat"
    />
    <feBlend
        id="glow__svg__resBlend"
        in="SourceGraphic"
        in2="glow__svg__sat"
    />
</filter>
</svg>
       
        </filter>
```